# ssh pair key authentication problem

Tags: server, ssh, password, authentication

I have a problem with public and private key authentication.
I do this steps and then, public-key based doesn't work.
1- generate a pair of private and public key (RSA) using the following command:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/rc_ss/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/rc_ss/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/rc_ss/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/rc_ss/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
ac:fd:d1:2e:e5:1e:db:87:98:77:9e:14:62:db:97:f0 rc_ss@rc_ss-network
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|       .         |
|        S    + . |
|       o   .o * o|
|      . . .oo+ E.|
|         ..o+++ =|
|          .o+..=.|
+-----------------+
```

2- copy it through network with ssh-copy-id as follows

```
rc_ss@rc_ss-network:~$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.2.100
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.100 (192.168.2.100)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 33:67:e0:02:b1:10:46:76:78:6b:1f:e2:55:9b:6a:a8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.100' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.168.2.100's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'root@192.168.2.100'", and check in:

  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

3- then, I want to get connected to server ssh without password, and deal with following:

```
rc_ss@rc_ss-network:~$ ssh root@192.168.2.100
root@192.168.2.100's password:
```

Which means the password required yet.
Can anybody help me?
Appreciate it.

Comment: If you run a `cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target machine, do you see the public key from the original machine?

Comment: Yes, I can see that.

Comment: Can you confirm that the permissions on `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` are `rwx------`, and that the ssh server's `sshd_config` specifies `PubkeyAuthentication yes`?

Comment: the permission of /root/.ssh/authorized_keys is : -rw-------
and that sshd_config is :PubkeyAuthentication yes

Comment: Oh sorry, my permission statement was wrong.  What you specified is correct.

Comment: I think this problem might be get from ssh-add or ssh-keyscan.

Comment: Does your remote host have SELinux set to enforcing?  If so, [this response](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication) suggests you may need to run `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` (I'm guessing on the remote host) if you used the `ssh-copy-id` command.

Comment: The remote host in not an Ubuntu(Whereas client is Ubuntu), just use of the linux kernel and is different OS. I don't have that command (resorecon ) on the remote machine.
-bash: restorecon: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the public key was correctly copied to the target server, you'll need to make sure that the SSH daemon supports passwordless login. This configuration is set in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and you need to make sure the following values are set:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

If those values are not set, you will need to set them and then restart SSH with `sudo service ssh restart` in a terminal.

Comment: These settings are correct in both of the server and client.
But Public Key Authentication doesn't work yet.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have any other idea? Appreciate it.